# Is MobileServiceSQLiteStore.DefineTable<T> necessary on every run and if so why?

Tags: ios, sqlite, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to improve app launch performance for subsequent logins (every login after the first) with my mobile app and after putting some stop watch diagnostics I can see that defining my 8 tables with `MobileServiceSQLiteStore.DefineTable<T>` takes on average 2.5 seconds. Every time.

On an iPhone 4 running iOS 7 the loading time would be less than a second if it weren't for having to define these tables every time. I would expect them to only need to be defined the first run of the app when the SQLite database is setup. I've tried removing the definitions on subsequent logins and try to just get the sync tables but it fails with "Table is not defined".

So, it seems this is the intended behavior. Can you explain why they need to be defined each time and/or if there is any workaround for this? It could be negligible considering my phone is pretty old now.. but it still is something I would like to remove if possible.

Comment: You might try attaching a profiler to see where the time is spent--that would help the dev team narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is required to be called every time because SDK uses it to know how to deserialize data if you read it via untyped interface i.e. `IMobileServiceSyncTable` instead of `IMobileServiceSyncTable<T>`.

As of now there is no work around to avoid calling it each time. I'm surprised however that it is taking 2.5 seconds for you because DefineTable does not do any database operations. It merely inspects the members on your type/JObject and maintains an in memory dictionary for later re-use.

I would recommend you to download and compile the SDK and debug your way through to figure out where the time is actually spent.